# Python, calling mmap with too-large address causes overflow exception

Tags: python, posix

I am converting some C code that accesses a device driver via mmap.  I thought I could easily do very similar things in Python.  However I've run into this issue.  The address that needs to be mmap'ed is provided by the PCI configuration, so I have no control over this address.  In this case, the address found is 3451912192.  The address field is of course an unsigned integer, and is 32-bits.

This address just happens to be in the range where it fits in an unsigned integer but not a signed integer.  When I call mmap, I get the following exception:

```
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int
```

So Python is artificially telling me the number doesn't fit because it thinks it's signed.  Is it possible to resolve this somehow, or do I have to do the mmap call in C?

Note that converting the pointer to the equivalent negative value gives:

```
OverflowError: memory mapped offset must be positive
```

eryksun points out that the C interface actually specifies a signed value, so Python is correct from a semantic point of view but it won't let me circumvent this restriction which the C program is able to ignore.

Indeed, `lspci` reveals that the device has resource:

```
Memory at cdc00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
```

and `0xcdc00000==3451912192`.  It would seem at the very least that the check for `offset > 0` in `mmap` is perhaps not correct.  Why check this?  Let the operating system return an error code if it's not supported.

Comment: what are you passing as the first argument to mmap (fd)?

Comment: the output of `posix.open("/dev/mem", posix.O_RDWR)`.

Comment: @eryksum: it's a 32-bit system.  You're right, `off_t` is indeed a signed type.  Nonetheless I've verified that the C code I'm trying to copy is passing such a value.  If I convert it to the equivalent negative value the `mmap` module also gives me an error.  I guess I could try implementing my own `mmap` through ctypes.

Comment: I'd report this as a bug on the python tracker.

Comment: I ran into the same problem but didn't have ctypes available and ended up writing a python extension. But, the outcome will be the same. You just put the offset in the C code and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once, I also wanted to `mmap` a bigger-then-4GB chunk of data on a 64bit machine into a 64bit-compiled Python.

If I remember correctly the main reason it it did not work out was, that most fundamental python-object `struct` contains an **object size** member, which is only **32bit**. And to change this is so difficult, that you could say, you need to overhaul the whole language, and especially fix all compiled extensions.

I am not sure, but this might has been done with Python 3.0.